# How to make smarty output debug info when template fails to compile?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm already set its `debugging` option to `true`,but when there's error in smarty template(i.e. there is no corresponding plugin for a specific `smarty_modifier`),nothing is output for information.

**UPDATE**

For anyone that wants to have a try,this is the most simple template I can think of :

```
{$var|nosuch_modifier}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- First, you can check if error_reporting is on. this is usually done in php.ini but you can place these statements on top of your php source.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

and make sure it is not disabled elsewhere.

2- smarty may report errors as throwing an exception. You can define a global exception handler to catch them, here is an example;

```
try {
    // place your code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I just tried,but there's no exception.I've configured PHP to output errors already.

Answer (score 0):

Update upon comments:

The only reason I can think of is that you've set `compile_check` to false.

```
$tpl->compile_check = false;
```

In this case, Smarty will show the latest compiled source, whatever you do to the tpl file. So, did you check and set `compile_check` to true?

```
$tpl->compile_check = true;
```

<strike>Try</strike>

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in the PHP code.

Comment: Ah, that 3 minute rule. Same answer at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging console](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/chapter.debugging.console.php), [`$error_reporting`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/variable.error.reporting.php) and [`trigger_error()`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.trigger.error.php)?

Comment: Can you try to execute the most simplified template `{$var|nosuch_modifier}` ?

Comment: It works for me, you must check your PHP error reporting and error level, template compile_check, template cache_check etc one by one. There is no reason not to show anything if all of these are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty error reporting can be set manually.

```
$smarty->error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE;
```

Some comments from the Smarty.class.php

> error muting is done because some people implemented custom
>   error_handlers using http://php.net/set_error_handler and for some
>   reason did not understand the following paragraph:
>
> It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is
>   completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types
>   unless the callback function returns FALSE. error_reporting() settings
>   will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless -
>   however you are still able to read the current value of
>   error_reporting and act appropriately. Of particular note is that this
>   value will be 0 if the statement that caused the error was prepended
>   by the @ error-control operator.
>
> Smarty deliberately uses @filemtime() over file_exists() and
>   filemtime() in some places. Reasons include
>   - @filemtime() is almost twice as fast as using an additional file_exists()
>   - between file_exists() and filemtime() a possible race condition is opened, which does not exist using the simple @filemtime() approach.